# Getting span tag contents?

Tags: c#, tags, html-agility-pack, html

Okay so I want to get the plot summary from within the `<span>` tag, and it does not seem to work for all webpages.

This is what I have:

```
private ArrayList getSynopsis()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < animeURLList.Count; i++)
    {

            var mainURL = "http://www.animenewsnetwork.com";
            var theHTML = wc.DownloadString(mainURL + (string) animeURLList[i]);
            MessageBox.Show(theHTML);
            //inner html for the span info
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(theHTML);
            //var array = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='infotype-12'][@class='encyc-info-type br']);
            //MessageBox.Show("got here" + array.ToString());
            ArrayList synopList = new ArrayList();;

            foreach (HtmlNode node doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='infotype-12'][@class='encyc-info-type br']"))
            {
                    synopList.Add(node.GetAttributeValue("span", "null"));
            }

    }
    return null;
}
```

I am trying to grab the text from:

```
<div id="infotype-12" class="encyc-info-type br">
<strong>Plot Summary:</strong> 
<span>Tooru takes a test so she can enter the same high school as Run, the girl she     likes. She passes, but when she goes to tell Run, she finds her hugging a girl she's never     seen before.</span>
</div>
```

The span tag  has the plot summary in it which is what i am trying to grab.

I am still unable to understand this.

Comment: Thanks for the markup. Having your HAP code as well would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your loop:

```
synopList.Add(node.SelectSingleNode("span").InnerText);
```

Additionally, the XPath you are using:

```
"//div[@id='infotype-12'][@class='encyc-info-type br']"
```

Would be better as:

```
"//div[@id='infotype-12' and @class='encyc-info-type br']"
```

Comment: so the first message comes up but then after it just gives me: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @RyanGlen - Well, your last statement in the function is `return null;`... Should probably be `return synopList;`.

Comment: I changed that, and I get this: http://i.imgur.com/nv7ra.png, it makes no sense because the first synopsis comes up then that error occurs.

Comment: @RyanGlen - I see now. Put the result of `SelectNodes` into a variable and iterate over it. The way your code is written now, it tries to refetch the node list again and again.

Comment: @RyanGlen - Yes, it is. Did you put a breakpoint on the `foreach` and check what the value of `nodez` is. It is possible that no nodes are getting selected.

Comment: @RyanGlen - Also, check the source HTML again - it may have changed?

Comment: @RyanGlen - It might not be an `HtmlNode` - try using `var` and see what the type of the node is.

Comment: It says this: http://i.imgur.com/95UBT.png, then I click ok and then the first synopsis comes up for the anime and then this happens: http://i.imgur.com/LANOY.png

Comment: This is the code which sets animeURLList and gives it the URLs btw: http://pastebin.com/NMvQ03Yp I know theres nothing wrong with it because it gave me every one of the URLs perfectly, but maybe there may be another issue which I didnt see.

Comment: @RyanGlen - second time around the loop (`animeURLList`), are you certain the complete URL is valid and that the HTML is in the expected format?

Comment: How about I send you my entire code so you can look at it?: http://pastebin.com/VxP90XA9 Because I think everything's working.